# How to extract special set of string/words from a list based on a given pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have below list of name_space characters:

```
existing_list = ['ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns24:Product/ns24:dpname','ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns25:Event/ns25:evtname','ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns26:Account/ns26:actnum']

updated_list = ['ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns14:Product/ns14:dpname','ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns15:Event/ns15:evtname','ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns16:Account/ns16:actnum']
```

Now I have to verify the pattern of item from the `existing_list` if those have been changed in the 'updated_list'.

For example: The namspace:

```
ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns24:Product/ns24:dpname
```

from `existing_list` has been updated  with

```
ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns14:Product/ns14:dpname
```

in the 'updated_list' - i.e. number changed from `24` to `14`

I am looking for a way to extract the pattern of string without including the 'ns' value, in this case
'Insurance/Policy/Product/dpname' from the 'updated_list'.

Here the pattern 'Insurance/Policy/Product/dpname' is available in the 'updated_list'

if I search for the pattern without 'ns' from `existing_list` - i.e., 'Insurance/Policy/Product/dpname'

```
# ie:
pattern_string = 'Insurance/Policy/Product/dpname'
for element in updated_list:
    result = re.match(pattern_string, element)
```

it should return:

```
''ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns14:Product/ns14:dpname'' # from the 'updated_list'
```

because we are checking to get the updated ns value from the `updated_list`.

What is the right approach to get this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question with an example input and output, that will be helpful, i am able to get what you are saying but still needs some calrification

Comment: Hi @SARANSURYA i have elaborated the expected result. by the way  i am looking the way to find and extract the pattern of string for example in this case "Insurance/Policy/Product/dpname'

Comment: Hi @SARANSURYA.. can you please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

@Cloud_Hari kindly try this solution,

```py
import re
pattern = r"([\d]+)"
numbers = []
existing_list = ['ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns24:Product/ns24:dpname','ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns25:Event/ns25:evtname','ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns26:Account/ns26:actnum']
updated_list=['ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns14:Product/ns14:dpname','ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns15:Event/ns15:evtname','ns:Insurance/ns:Policy/ns16:Account/ns16:actnum']

for previous, current in zip(existing_list, updated_list):
    if re.findall(pattern, previous)[0] != re.findall(pattern, current)[0]:
        print("previous list value => ", previous)
        print("Has been updated to => ", current)
        #Feel free to add your logic here
```

This uses REGEX to match the occurrences of the number in the previous list and compare it with the second list, and if they are different they will print them out, and you can add your logic inside the if block.

The REGEX pattern => ([\d+]) forms a group of matching decimals.